# Incorporating a dictionary in to an HTML system to ensure a word exists

Tags: javascript, html, dictionary

I am at my very wits end with this, I am currently trying to incorporate a dictionary into my HTML system that checks whether a word is real or not. I currently have a "words.txt" document that I am using as a dictionary. I remember learning of a method that allows you to search through a document for a word but could not find any information on it and was going to use this as a way to check if a word exists. Currently I have no qualms with how long it takes to find the word, just whether it could find it at all.

so currently I'm intending to make it so a user would use a text box, enter a word and this word would be cross referenced with the dictionary, if the word is found it would alert the user that the word exists. I'm just unsure how to do this.

However if there is a better or easier method of doing this, then I would be much appreciative of your input.

Thanks in advance. And I would happy to specify anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an `xmlhttprequest` to load the dictionary file, and once it loads, dump it inside an array. Then, every time a key is lifted (or however you want to check the spelling of a word), a function can be called that compares the word with the words in the dictionary.

Here's one way to do it:

HTML:

```
<textarea onkeyup="check(this)"></textarea>
```

Javascript:

```
//A large array of dictionary words
var dictionary = new Array();




//First, let's load up the dictionary
address = "words.txt";


//Create an XMLHTTPRequest object
var req = (window.XMLHttpRequest)?new XMLHttpRequest():new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
if(req == null) {
    console.log("Error: XMLHttpRequest failed to initiate.");
}

//When it loads, add all the elements to the dictionary array
req.onload = function() {

    dictionary = req.responseText.split("\n");


    //Convert all the characters to lowercase. That way, multi-case strings are allowed.
    for(var i = 0; i < dictionary.length; i++)
        dictionary[i] = dictionary[i].toLowerCase();



}
try {

    req.open("GET", address, true);
    req.send(null);

} catch(e) {
    console.log("Oh snap");
}









//This function is called every time a key is released
function check(element) {

    var allWords = element.value.split(" ");


    for(var i = 0; i < allWords.length; i++) {


        if(dictionary.indexOf(allWords[i].toLowerCase()) == -1) {
            element.style.backgroundColor = "#FFF";
            return;
        }

    }

    element.style.backgroundColor = "#0F0";

}
```

Edit: Modified to the code to work for textareas

Comment: @JeffreySweeny: What about multiple same words?

Comment: @David It still works, assuming I'm understanding what you're saying. The `indexOf` function will return -1 if the word does not exist at all in the dictionary. If a user types "apples apples", this will still work. However, this code is not without problems, such as double spaces and new lines. This is easy to fix, but the extra code probably won't be necessary for the example.

Comment: This is brilliant! So if I'm reading this correctly I need to simply create an html text box and hook this JavaScript up to it, and it should work? In terms of the dictionary used in this case "words.txt" would I need a delimiter between each word, as currently my "words.txt" is essentially one very long word as it doesn't include spaces

Comment: @Joel.Conway You will need a delimiter, though it doesn't need to be a new line (\n). Again, this code isn't perfect, but it's something to get you started.

Comment: @JeffreySweeney thank you so much for this, honestly I've been very stressed out and this has been a huge help to get me started.

Answer (score 2):

A trie data structure is good for a dictionary. A trie is tree of words sorts by each letter. Here is a good explanation but for PHP: http://phpir.com/tries-and-wildcards.

Comment: This system works well, but from what I gathered from this article I would need to enter every word individually whereas I already have access to a dictionary file, is it possible I could simply look through my file to find an entered word?

Comment: @Joel.Conway: It's about using a tree and have a fast lookup. If this is a newbie question how can you suggest such a complicated mechanic? A trie is more simplier when you understand it but it needs a bit more effort to make. I'm sure you can find some JS trie.

Comment: @Joel.Conway Depending on your target audience, implementing some of the optimization techniques David posted would definitely be beneficial; with my code, a ten-year old brickputer will noticeably chug through the dictionary list.

Comment: @JeffreySweeney: Not only that but if you store in online you can have many parallel users. Anyway a hash map is good too. I didn't know you have already a dictionary. My apologize.